# Laravel not sending email to environment variable

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am using the following working code in Laravel:

```php
Mail::to('mail@example.com')->send(new \App\Mail\CheckinInfo([
   'client' => $client,
]));
```

when I use an email address from the environment, it stopped working:

```
Mail::to(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'))->send(new \App\Mail\CheckinInfo([
   'client' => $client,
]));
```

In `.env` I got:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mail@example.com
```

and I tried

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="mail@example.com"
```

The cache and config are cleared.

The error message is:

```
[2022-07-29 18:44:26] production.ERROR: An email must have a "To", "Cc", or "Bcc" header. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Mime\\Exception\\LogicException(code: 0): An email must have a \"To\", \"Cc\", or \"Bcc\" header. at /www/htdocs/app/laravel/vendor/symfony/mime/Message.php:128)
```

Comment: Try running `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: That's what I mean with "The cache is cleared". I already did that.

Answer (score 1):

As a note when you do a config:cache the settings will not be grabbed from your .env anymore.

You should create a config/settings.php or similar file and store your env vars there, ie:

`config/settings.php`

```
return [
  'mail_from_address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
]
```

and you should reference it as so

```
config('settings.mail_from_address')
```

Comment: This ends in the exact same error

Comment: have you tried doing a `dd(config('settings.mail_from_address'))` to see what is being outputed?  maybe you have a typo in your ENV var.

Answer (score 0):

No your mistake on the first line, maybe you didn't close the bracket
Try this way

```
    Mail::to(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'))->send(new \App\Mail\CheckinInfo([
        'client' => $client,
     ])); //Notice I added the closing parenthesis for To()
```

You are trying to access the functions of the env methods. This is not possible
I hope this is just the problem
You can see the documentation for the framework,
about this   [queueing-mail laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#queueing-mail)

Comment: It's a typo in my question, but good point, though.